# Unable to install Spinnaker via Helm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, spinnaker

While trying to install spinnaker with below command , i am facing Error.

Command: `helm install spinnaker stable/spinnaker -f values.yaml`

**Error**

```
unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: [unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta2", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "StatefulSet" in version "apps/v1beta2"]
```

**My kubernetes Version:**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.2", GitCommit:"52c56ce7a8272c798dbc29846288d7cd9fbae032", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-04-16T11:56:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.3", GitCommit:"2e7996e3e2712684bc73f0dec0200d64eec7fe40", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-05-20T12:43:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**My Helm Version:**

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.4", GitCommit:"0ad800ef43d3b826f31a5ad8dfbb4fe05d143688", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.12"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed recently in [this PR](https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/20917) in the version `2.x` of the chart. Use the latest version to install

```
helm install spinnaker stable/spinnaker --version 2.0.0-rc9 --timeout 600 -f values.yaml
```

Comment: i am using above command,i am facing Error :Error: failed post-install: timed out waiting for the condition

Comment: still facing same issue. spin-clouddriver,spin-deck,spin-echo,spin-front50,spin-gate,spin-igor,spin-orca-spin-rosco pods are in ''ImagePullBackOff" status and spinnaker-minio,redis,halyard pods are in running status

Comment: share output of kubectl get events

Comment: After changing minikube MAC Address to static,it's start but facing below issue:Unable to get host IP: ip for interface (): Error finding IPV4 address for vEthernet ()

Comment: As far as this question is concerned its answered..ask a different question for this with details

Comment: how to get url for spinnaker .i am using this command 1)minikube service spin-deck --namespace=spinnaker 2)minikube service spin-deck --url .but it's shows: service spinnaker/spin-deck has no node port

Comment: the chart does not create it...you need to create a nodeport type service manually